# MS Access VBA Correct Week Number between years

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need help with this function. I have a table where based on the posting date I need to assign which week it falls on.

Our week starts on Saturday, so this workaround that Microsoft published some years ago -- doesn't work.

```
Public Function WOY(MyDate As Date) As Integer    ' Week Of Year

  WOY = Format(MyDate, "ww", vbSaturday, vbFirstFourDays)
  If WOY > 52 Then
    If Format(MyDate + 7, "ww", vbSaturday, vbFirstFourDays) = 2 Then WOY = 1
  End If

End Function
```

[image: Here is an example]

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Valglad

Comment: "doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Results look fine to me.

Comment: You need to define what "correct" is. `52*7=364`, and there are 365 days in a year: if you define a "year" as 364 days, then you can have 4 quarters with 3 months, respectively with 3, 4, and 3 full 7-days weeks that line up year-over-year. And every so often, the calendar needs a 53rd week to account for the accrued "lost day". Since you're in Access consider making a table with a record per date (date is unique but not PK), and columns like `MonthOfYear`, `WeekOfMonth`, etc.; then the "correct" calendar can be whatever your business needs it to be.

Comment: And 366 days during leap year.

Comment: By doesn't work I meant it goes into week 53. Based on our manufacturing requirements, we have to have only 52 weeks per year. So that would make week 1 start on Dec 28th. Sorry I neglected to explain it properly. If our week would start on Monday -- the code in my original message would flip from 52 to 1 without any issues.

Comment: Even a Monday start would calculate 53 weeks sometimes - 12/28/2026.

Comment: wow I meant 4-5-4, not 3-4-3, 13 weeks per quarter....lol - anyway having a 53rd week should be expected, because there aren't 364 days in a year.

Comment: There is an ISO Standard for week numbers. It might be worth considering this if your week numbers are communicated to the outside world. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a unique solution here because part of the definition of Week is that it starts on Monday:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/functions-return-wrong-week-number
One answer That is easy to convert is to assume that Each Saturday gets the same Week Number as the following Monday.  Adapting the working solution from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/functions-return-wrong-week-number#workarounds

```
Public Function WOY(MyDate As Date) As Integer    ' Week Of Year
MyDate = DateAdd("d", 2, MyDate) 'assuming Saturday gets the same weeknumber as the following Monday 
  WOY = Format(MyDate, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
  If WOY > 52 Then
    If Format(MyDate + 7, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 2 Then WOY = 1 'borrowing Microsofts solution to handle all edge cases
  End If
End Function
```

This solution is conceptually simple but then 12/28/19 starts week 1 of 2020.

Comment: Tested. 12/26/2026 still returns week 53.

Comment: Only a year starting or concluding on a Thursday has 53 calendar weeks according to some of the references in my answer.  12/26/2026 is a thursday so in this case my solution seems correct.

Comment: My Windows calendar says 12/26/2026 is a Saturday. Did you run the date through your function?

Comment: 12/26/2026 is a saturday, but 2026 ends on a thursday, hence the last week is #53.

Comment: Why did you state 12/26/2026 is a Thursday? How does this function address the OP requirement?

Comment: not that I know how, but lets discuss this outside the comments section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230584/discussion-between-mazoula-and-june7).

Answer (score 0):

> If our week would start on Monday -- the code in my original message
> would flip from 52 to 1 without any issues

For this year perhaps, but not for any year.

Thus, the answer is - as Mathieu clearly explained: *There is no solution to your question*.

It is for a reason, that the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard was created where week numbering is an important part, as the first and last week may span calendar year boundaries.

You may use any other week numbering system, but most likely it will have shortcomings as you have seen.